# Swift - get field from randomly created document ID (Firestore)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

in my application the user can sign up and by doing that I also save the `firstname`, `lastname` and `uid`.

This is how Firestore-Database looks like:

[image]

I would like to access the users `lastname` but I do not know how, as the `Document-ID` gets created randomly in the sign-up process.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in

            //check for errors
            if let err = err {
                self.view.endEditing(true)
                self.showError(err.localizedDescription)

            }else {

                //user was created successfully; store first and last name
                let db = Firestore.firestore()

                db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstname":firstName, "lastname": lastName, "uid": result!.user.uid]) { (error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        self.showError("Error saving user data")
                    }
                }

                //transition to home
                self.transitionToHome()
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know one of two things in order to get a document in Firestore:

1. The full path of the document, including the name of the collection and ID of the document (and any nested subcollections and document IDs)
2. Something about the data in that document, for example, a value of one of its fields.

If you don't know either of these things, then all you can do is fetch all the documents in a collection and try to figure out what you want by looking at everything in the collection.

The bottom line is that if you don't know which document belongs with which user, you are kind of stuck.  You should store the ID of the user in the document, or as the ID of the document itself, so that you can use it to find that document later.

I suggest using the Firebase Auth user ID as the ID of the document.  This is extremely common.  Don't use addDocument to write it with a random ID, [use setData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) with the ID you know.

Firestore cannot just know which document you want at any time, unless you provide a way for it to locate the document.

Comment: I got it working by using `setData` and the Firebase Auth user ID just like you said. Thanks :)